# Highlighting menu section not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, menu, highlight

I'm working on a project that requires 2 distinct menus, one on top, and one on the left of the page:

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul class="navigation">
     <li><a href="../index.html">FILM </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
     <li><a href="../../photography/index.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
     <li><a href="../../other/index.html">OTHER WORKS </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
     <li><a href="../../about/index.html">INFO/INQUIRE </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="navigationLeft">    
<ul class="navigationLeft">
<li><a href='../item1/index.html'><span>item 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href='../item2/index.html'><span>item 2</span></a></li>
<li><a href='../item3/index.html'><span>item 3</span></a></li>
<li><a href='../item4/index.html'><span>item 4</span></a></li>
</ul>         
</div>
```

The left one is basically a sort of sub-menu of a section in the top menu. Originally, the project was meant to be small, so I used straight CSS to highlight selected sections using class, but the website has grown so much now that I want to use templating for future updates. That means that straight CSS is now out. I've implemented the following script in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".navigationLeft a").each(function() {
    if (this.href == window.location) {
        $(this).css("color", "#ff9900");
    };
});
});
</script>
```

It's working for my left menu, but obviously wouldn't work for my top menu, because technically the section that I'm in isn't the "current page". I'm looking for a way using jQuery/js to parse through the url and have the highlighting applied to any link that is once up the tree. So basically, in my top menu, any `<a href>` that contained for example `/photography/` would also be highlighted, even though it's not technically the current page. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: *Disclaimer: I really don't know anything about js so I tend to patch things together*
I figured it out, I just added a second script in my header:
    `<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
    $(".navigationLeft a").each(function() {
     if (this.href == window.location) {
    $(".navigation li:first a" ).css("color", "#ff9900");
    };
    });
    });
    </script>`
It works, and I can apply it to other page by simply replacing `li:first` with `li:nth-child()`, huzzah!